# vba code to copy data from one cell and paste it in dynamic range in excel

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I want to copy the data which is in cell C2 and paste it for the cells C3:C10000. This (C10000) may change in future and is dynamic. Please help me to write a VBA code to copy-paste the data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved as below, this will check the last row with data on Column A (Assuming that the dynamic range will populate Column A with data) and copy the value from C2 all the way down to the last row:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row in Column A, to find how far down the value of C2 should be copied to
ws.Range("C2").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
End Sub
```